# HttpArchvie - BigQuery : How to get list of pages with most number of 3rd party scripts?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to fetch the list of URL's (html pages) with most number of third party scripts using the below query. BTW, am trying to query the httparchive database(httparchive.org)

```
SELECT req_referer, count(url) as js_count
   FROM [httparchive:runs.latest_requests]
   WHERE mimeType='application/javascript' \
   AND DOMAIN(url) != DOMAIN(req_referer)
   GROUP BY req_referer
   ORDER BY js_count DESC
```

I am not confident on the query result. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: But the last line should read ORDER BY... uh?

Comment: @JavierRuiz, thanks. corrected the typo.